# How to get the UniqueId of a Onedrive (for business) file?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to get the UniqueId of my files in one drive. If you select a file and then download it, the download link contains the unique id. Additionally, if you share one of your word, powerpoint, excel and similar files with only specific people, the sharable link contains the uinque id but not for other files like photos and videos for which only the path of the file is seen in the link.

Is there anyway to get the unique id for photos and videos like it could be gotten for word and excel files? Is there any API that allows me to do so?

Thanks for answeiring.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: Yes, for sure thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<Item ID>/children?$select=id,name
```

Result:

I have 3 files under a folder, so this is my request and result:
[image]
[image]

If you are not sure about your folder item id, use the request below to get all item id under root:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/children?$select=id,name
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

More about this, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_children?view=odsp-graph-online).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please let me know why this does not work (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<itemId>?$select=id,name,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl), it retrieves the id and name but not the downloadUrl

Comment: @ZyadOmer999, if you want to download files, you should use this  API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Could you please show me like the previous example? I tried but it gives me error

Comment: @ZyadOmer999,sure, please ask another question and let me know the link : )

Comment: This is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65883820/13781834