# How to get the download URL onedrive graph api?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Could you please let me know why this does not work?
http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/%3CitemId%3E?$select=id,name,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
it retrieves the id and name but not the downloadUr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reponse,this is a known issue of Microsoft Graph API. For your requirement,use `content.downloadUrl` instead of `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`, just try this :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<item id>/children?$select=content.downloadUrl,id,name
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try using `select` instead of `$select` and it should work.